# using tun0 on centos6

Tags: centos, openvpn

I'm connected to a VPN known to work from server-side (I can connect to it on Windows).  I cannot use the VPN on Centos6.

ping -I tun0 www.google.com

```
Warning: cannot bind to specified iface, falling back: Operation not permitted
PING www.l.google.com (74.125.224.50) from 192.168.1.139 tun0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.l.google.com ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 11905ms
```

ifconfig:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
inet addr:10.208.82.118  P-t-P:10.208.82.117  Mask:255.255.255.255
UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
RX bytes:168 (168.0 b)  TX bytes:9996 (9.7 KiB)
```

Openvpn claims that I'm connected:

```
Thu May 17 12:46:11 2012 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.1.254
Thu May 17 12:46:11 2012 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Thu May 17 12:46:11 2012 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Thu May 17 12:46:11 2012 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Thu May 17 12:46:11 2012 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.208.82.118 peer 10.208.82.117
Thu May 17 12:46:11 2012 /sbin/ip route add 10.20.16.0/20 via 10.208.82.117
Thu May 17 12:46:11 2012 /sbin/ip route add 10.208.82.1/32 via 10.208.82.117
Thu May 17 12:46:11 2012 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Kernel IP routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.208.82.117   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.208.82.1     10.208.82.117   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
10.20.16.0      10.208.82.117   255.255.240.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
```

Not sure what else would be helpful, but would be glad to provide it.  Thanks in advance.